# How to remove all zeros in list

Tags: python

i need to remove all zeros from my array but it doesn't work!

```
array = [9, 0, 0, 9, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9]
for i in array:
    if i == 0:
        array.remove(i)
print(array)
```

output:

```
[9, 9, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 9]
```

i really don't know what the problem. Please helm me!

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
x = [9, 0, 0, 9, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9]
x = [i for i in x if i != 0]
print(x)
```